# Remove html tag from an html content using perl HTML::Strip

Tags: html, perl

I am trying to remove the tags of the html content without changing it format. I have tried both HTML::Strip and HTML::Restrict but it's not giving the expected output.

I need to get the output as

```
Heading
point 1
point 2
```

This is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Restrict;
use HTML::Strip;
my $hs = HTML::Strip->new();
my $hr = HTML::Restrict->new();
my $tree = '<div><span itemprop="description">Heading<ul><li>point 1</li><li>point 2</li></ul></span></div>';
my $processed = $hr->process($tree);
my $clean_text = $hs->parse($tree);
print "$clean_text\n\n";
print "$processed\n\n";
```

but I am getting the output as

```
Heading point 1 point 2
```

Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't quite get the output you want, buut for the general case you want (html -> text format) you could look at [HTML::FormatText](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aFormatText).

```
C:\Users\User>perl -MHTML::TreeBuilder -MHTML::FormatText -E "
      my $html = '<div><span itemprop="description">Heading<ul><li>point 1</li><li>point 2</li></ul></span></div>'; 
      my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html); 
      say $tree->format(HTML::FormatText->new);
"
```

Gives output:

```
Heading

     * point 1

     * point 2
```

Answer (score 1):

well, the HTML does just that - formats the text. Once you get rid of the HTML tags, you get rid of the format of the text also.

Think of it this way - right now, you're interested in keeping only the newlines from the format. How should the parser know how to transform `<ul><li>`s in newlines?

What if you'd want to keep the `**bold**`ness of the text in the future?

As a potential alternative solution, have a look at [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

Or, parse the DOM of the HTML using a [`XML::DOM::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aDOM%3a%3aLite) processor and transform individual HTML elements into their text file format equivalents